# я хочу установить модуль discord но выдает ошибку

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
Requirement already satisfied: discord.py in c:\users\timur\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (1.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0 in c:\users\timur\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from discord.py) (3.7.4.post0)
Requirement already satisfied: yarl<2.0,>=1.0 in c:\users\timur\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py) (1.7.2)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.3.0 in c:\users\timur\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py) (21.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: async-timeout<4.0,>=3.0 in c:\users\timur\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py) (3.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<5.0,>=2.0 in c:\users\timur\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py) (4.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.6.5 in c:\users\timur\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py) (4.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: multidict<7.0,>=4.5 in c:\users\timur\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py) (6.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.0 in c:\users\timur\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from yarl<2.0,>=1.0->aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py) (3.3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Никакой ошибки нет и у вас все установилось. Попробуйте запустить `python -c "import discord"` в вашей консоли. Если никаких ошибок нет, значит, все работает.

Comment: спасибо, я думал что я делаю что то не так

Answer (score 0):

Это не ошибка. Всё что оно пишет это, то что всё уже установлено.

Попробуй запустить такой скрипт, если не будет ошибки всё ок:

```py
import discord
```